# What to do in "pd.read_csv" when "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 9, saw 5" is returned?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the file created as temp.cvs

[temp.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhTj.png)

I've made the above file into temp.csv.
Then ran the following.

```py
df=pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
df
```

Then I got

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line
>   9, saw 5

So I tried

```py
df=pd.read_csv("temp.csv",error_bad_lines=False)
df
```

and got.

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf840
>
> 0 {\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 HelveticaNeue;}
>
> 1 {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red53\gre...
>
> 2 {*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c27059\c27059\c2...
>
> 3 \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\v...
>
> 4 \deftab560
>
> 5 \pard\pardeftab560\slleading20\partightenfactor0

I still do not know what the problem is... Please HELP me...

Answer (score 7):

To fix that you need to add the separator in the code:

> df = pd.read_csv("temp.csv", sep=";")

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv',sep='\t',
                  lineterminator='\r',
                  error_bad_lines=False)
```